# How to create multipart/mixed POST request body for Olingo OData4 while Batch processing of file upload?

Tags: rest, post, odata, multipart, olingo

I'm able to use multipart request body for file upload using **Postman** for Apache Olingo Odata batch processing. However, looking to generate same request using **Olingo client APIs**. That is, for example taking an analogy of Apache HTTPClient, there is a [MultipartEntityBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196369/how-to-create-multipart-mixed-request-with-xml-in-the-request-body-with-java) which does the needful, looking for same with Olingo Odata4 client.

Below Batch request works fine in **Postman**:

```
https://hostname:443/MyApp/servlet/odata/MyDomain/$batch
....
Content-Type multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_50f02a08-698b-4af0-b19a-1fcb75d244d8
```

Raw request body used in **Postman**:

```
--batch_50f02a08-698b-4af0-b19a-1fcb75d244d8
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:1

PUT https://hostname:443/MyApp/servlet/odata/MyDomain/Documents('OID:my.doc.Document:12345')/MyContent/$value HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ContentSeparator
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-ID: 1

--ContentSeparator
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFilepathInput";filename="myFile1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, World!
This is a text file.

--ContentSeparator--

--batch_50f02a08-698b-4af0-b19a-1fcb75d244d8--
```

In order to generate above raw request body, I tried below 2 approaches but the problem is such that I'm not able to generate a **boundary separated part**(below) in the body:

```
--ContentSeparator
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFilepathInput";filename="myFile1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, World!
This is a text file.

--ContentSeparator--
```

**1)** Using `ODataEntityUpdateRequest`. Pseudo code to generate request body is below:

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
ODataBatchRequest req = client.getBatchRequestFactory().getBatchRequest(batchBaseURI.toString());
BatchManager payloadManager = batchRequest.payloadManager();
//Unnecessary lines removed..
File file = new File(filepath.toString());
ClientEntity entity = client.getObjectFactory().newEntity(qualifiedName);
//Unnecessary lines removed...
entity.setMediaContentSource(file.toURI());
entity.setMediaContentType(ContentType.parse("text/html").toContentTypeString());
entity.setMediaEntity(true);

URI insertUri = //A PUT request URI. Unnecessary lines removed...

CUDRequestFactory requestFactory = client.getCUDRequestFactory();
ODataEntityUpdateRequest<ClientEntity> updateRequest = requestFactory.getEntityUpdateRequest(insertUri, UpdateType.REPLACE, entity);
updateRequest.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
//Unnecessary lines removed...
payloadManager.addRequest(updateRequest);
```

This gives me request body as below with file information in JSON format:

```
--batch_a4ac4cb0-c851-4767-a043-e7df8b24e0fb
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID:1

PUT https://hostname:443/MyApp/servlet/odata/MyDomain/Documents('OID:my.doc.Document:12345')/MyContent/$value HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-ID: 1

{"FileName":"myFile1.txt","filePath":"D:/temp/myFile1.txt"}
--batch_a4ac4cb0-c851-4767-a043-e7df8b24e0fb—
```

**2)** Using `ODataMediaEntityUpdateRequest`. Pseudo code to generate request body is below:

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
ClientEntity entity = client.getObjectFactory().newEntity(qualifiedName);
//Unnecessary lines removed...

URI insertUri = //A Put request URI for PrimaryContent, highlighted in Green in below request body. Unnecessary lines removed...

CUDRequestFactory requestFactory = client.getCUDRequestFactory();
       ODataMediaEntityUpdateRequest<ClientEntity> updateMediaRequest = requestFactory.getMediaEntityUpdateRequest(insertUri, targetStream);
       updateMediaRequest.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
payloadManager.addRequest(updateMediaRequest);
```

This gives me request body as below with file contents, But without file related information and a separate boundary/part:

```
--batch_fc2c9fc0-4a9b-44cf-a7c1-84aabff2e106
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID:1

PUT https://hostname:443/MyApp/servlet/odata/MyDomain/Documents('OID:my.doc.Document:12345')/MyContent/$value HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-ID: 1

Hello, World!
This is a text file.
--batch_fc2c9fc0-4a9b-44cf-a7c1-84aabff2e106--
```